# What is the possible reason for a computer to malfunction after proper shutdown?

Tags: hardware-failure

Usually I found my computer dead or malfunctioning after I went back home after one day work. And yesterday the computer is going okay and I've shutdown it properly. Assuming no one touched the computer, what is the possible reasons for a computer to go nuts except overheat problem caused by dust and heat?

Comment: could be part failure due to anything.

Comment: This question currently is too vague to answer. *Exactly* what was wrong when you turned it on?

Answer (score 1):

Depletion of the battery that powers the Real Time Clock (RTC) chip and mice.

Comment: never seen it, but possible i guess.